# multi dimensional array debugging outofboundsexception

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to make two 3 by 3 arrays (with predetermeined indexes) that will add themselves and display the output but I keep on getting an OOBE (out of bounds exception) error

```
// The "Matrixsum" class.
import java.awt.*;
import hsa.Console;

public class Matrixsum
{
    static Console c;           // The output console

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        c = new Console ();

        int array[] [] = {{4, 5, 3}, {6, 8, 3}, {1, 2, 3}};
        int array1[] [] = {{5, 4, 3}, {5, 6, 3}{1, 2, 3}};

        c.println ("Number of Row= " + array.length);
        c.println ("Number of Column= " + array [1].length);

        int l = array.length;

        c.println ("\t\t\nMatrix 1 :\n ");
        for (int row = 0 ; row < l ; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0 ; col <= l ; col++)
            {
                c.print (" " + array [row] [col]);
            }
            c.println ();
        }
        int L1 = array1.length;
        c.println ("Matrix 2 : ");
        for (int row = 0 ; row < L1 ; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0 ; col <= L1 ; col++)
            {
                c.print (" " + array1 [row] [col]);
            }
            c.println ();
        }
        c.println ("Addition of both matrix : ");
        for (int row = 0 ; row < L1 ; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0 ; col <= L1 ; col++)
            {
                c.print (" " + (array [row] [col] + array1 [row] [col]));
            }
            c.println ();
        }


        // Place your program here.  'c' is the output console
    } // main method
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Anywhere where you are doing `col <= L1`  or `col <= l` needs changed to  `col < L1`  and `col < l`

The max index of an array is always the length minus one because an array index starts at zero.

Comment: correct . this could also be found by debugging and seeing the value that gets too high compared to the size of the array.